# Calling WSH from Java

Tags: java, windows, vbscript, wsh

I have some wscript / vbscript based code that calls a certain COM API. This code needs to be run periodically with lots of other Java based code that we run in order to gather metrics.

I know that I could take this code and translate it to something that uses Com4J, JNA or alike to mimic the behaviour in Java. But the vbscript code is "certified" by the vendor of the application we measure and I want to avoid debates that when I translated the code I changed the validity of the measurements (we had a comparable debate before)
A second alternative would be to simply call wscript.exe as a subprocess, have it write the results to stdout and parse that. But I would rather avoid that because then I would have to check for stalled subprocesses etc.

Is there a different way to call WSH from Java ? Perhaps by calling the Windows Scripting Host as a COM Object and passing it a pointer to the sourcecode or the source in a String ?